MAUI Blazor Hyrid App Auth Not Working (.NET 8)
I have a new application that I am attempting to setup the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization components in. I have followed the guide from Microsoft here (see the Create a custom AuthenticationStateProvider with user change updates section). I have created the custom AuthenticationStateProvider implementation, added the AuthorizeRouteVie components to my routes, added the NotAuthorized child component for AuthorizeRouteView, I have added the CascadingAuthenticationState component, I have setup the necessary services in MauiProgram.cs, and I have added @attribute [Authorize] to _Imports.razor to secure all pages. However, when I run the application it still loads the MainLayout.razor with it's page components that should only be accessible by an authorized user. I have seen this message in the console:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed. These requirements were not met: DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
VetPlusAuthenticationStateProvider.cs
public class VetPlusAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private AuthenticationState currentUser;

    public VetPlusAuthenticationStateProvider(VetPlusAuthenticationService service)
    {
        currentUser = new AuthenticationState(service.CurrentUser);

        service.UserChanged += (newUser) =>
        {
            currentUser = new AuthenticationState(newUser);
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(currentUser));
        };
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() =>
        Task.FromResult(currentUser);
}

VetPlusAuthenticationService.cs
public class VetPlusAuthenticationService
{
    public event Action<ClaimsPrincipal>? UserChanged;
    private ClaimsPrincipal? currentUser;

    public ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get { return currentUser ?? new(); }
        set
        {
            currentUser = value;

            if (UserChanged is not null)
            {
                UserChanged(currentUser);
            }
        }
    }
}

Routes.razor
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Routes).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData"  DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <LoginRedirect />
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <h1>I AM AUTHORIZING</h1>
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

_Imports.razor
@using System.Net.Http
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using VetPlus.Shared
@using VetPlus.Shared.Layout
@using VetPlus.Shared.Pages
@using VetPlus.Shared.Components
@using VetPlus.Shared.Components.Redirect
@using VetPlus.Shared.Utils
@using DevExpress.Blazor

@attribute [Authorize]

MauiProgram.cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            });

        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

        builder.Services.AddDevExpressBlazor(options => {
            options.BootstrapVersion = BootstrapVersion.v5;
            options.SizeMode = DevExpress.Blazor.SizeMode.Medium;
        });

        builder.Services.AddOptions();
        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<VetPlusAuthenticationService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, VetPlusAuthenticationStateProvider>();

        builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
 #if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
 #endif

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPracticeHubClient, PracticeHubClient>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}

I am really unsure what I am missing here. I am uncertain how this affects the Microsoft guide, but all of the razor components for the project are in a Razor Class Library project that is referenced by the Maui project. I also noticed that I needed to adda reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization in order to use the @attribute [Authorize] attribute declaration. Is this package not compatible with the Maui project?

In the guide in the Program it says "Provide OpenID/MSAL code to authenticate the user. See your identity provider's documentation for details."  Where do you do it?  You have to get the current user from somewhere.
